# Trying to install Spark on a different drive

Tags: apache-spark, windows64

I'm trying to install Spark 2.3.0 on a Windows x64 machine, on the D drive. Specifically, I downloaded Spark 2.3.0 Hadoop 2.7. When I try to run `spark-shell`, I get the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main`

I've tried to follow a couple installation guides but nothing seems to work. `java -version` gives me:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Further, `python` gives:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I've added the following to my `PATH`:

- `D:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin`
- `D:\ProgramData\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin`
- `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin`
- `C:\Users\USER\.windows-build-tools\python27\`
- `D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

`JAVA_HOME` is set as `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`.

Finally, `scala` runs fine, producing:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_161).
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT 1:

Added contents of `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf`:

[image]

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @cricket_007, who pointed me to the Medium link [here](https://medium.com/@toashishagarwal/install-apache-spark-on-windows-3b970a1c0e3c). I was able to get somewhere? Here are the steps I've followed so far based on that article (note that relative links below are absolute paths in my system, I just don't want to lay out the whole directory structure):

1. Set SPARK_HOME variable as the location of the `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7` folder.
2. `spark-shell` resulted in `java.io.IOException` because it failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.
3. Downloaded the `winutils.exe` for Hadoop 2.7 and moved it to a folder `./winutils_hadoop/bin`.
4. Added `HADOOP_HOME` as a system-level environmental variable: `./winutils_hadoop/`.
5. Added `./winutils_hadoop/bin` to PATH variable.
6. Create directory `C:\tmp\hive`.
7. Run `winutils.exe chmod -R 777 C:\tmp\hive`.
8. `spark-shell` should now work.

However, this still gives a warning when running `spark-shell`: `WARN NativeCoderLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin java classes where applicable`.

Not only that, but the examples still don't run correctly. Running `javac ./spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java`, for example, results in several errors:

- `JavaWordCount.java:20: error: package scala does not exist`
- `JavaWordCount.java:22: error: package org.apache.api.java does not exist`
- `JavaWordCount.java:24: error: package org.apache.spark.sql does not exist`
- Etc.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Please add your spark-env file

Comment: @cricket_007 so this is probably me being an idiot, but what is that and where would I find it?

Comment: Spark 2.3.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

Comment: @Mahdi uninstalled Scala 2.12.5 and installed Scala 2.11.8. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: `spark-env` is in `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf` most likely

Comment: @cricket_007 added a picture of the contents of `spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf` (in the main post)

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but `spark-env.sh.template` is what you would configure on Mac/Linux to configure properties such as HADOOP_HOME or other Spark specific properties, including a classpath where it would look for files. I don't have a windows machine, though, so not sure where your error is coming from other than a Java classpath issue

Comment: @cricket_007 so in that file it says "Copy it as spark-env.sh and edit that to configure Spark for your site." It then lists like ~60 options, but no "HADOOP_HOME" is present. Instead I have HADOOP_CONF_DIR, is that the same thing?

Comment: They aren't, but `sh` files only run on Linux anyway, so I don't doubt that file will help you. I might suggest starting over. For example, see https://medium.com/@toashishagarwal/install-apache-spark-on-windows-3b970a1c0e3c

Comment: @cricket_007 followed the guide you linked and updated question with relevant info

Comment: 1) `Unable to load native-hadoop library` can safely be ignored. 2) You're supposed to run the JAR files in the examples, not compile the java classes yourself.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry for the confusion, it was assigned in this class to run the Java files... What directory are the Jar versions located in?

Comment: I don't remember the path right now, but in the documentation, it says `spark-submit 
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi 
  /path/to/examples.jar`

Comment: My point is that if you're going to use `javac`, you need to actually pass in Spark's classpath. The correct solution is use Maven to compile the examples folder. My suggestion otherwise, would be to use the Scala spark shell interpreter (if it loads) to run the Scala examples

Comment: Okay, so `spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi ./examples/jars` seems to work. So for `javac` is it along the lines of `spark-submit javac --class MISSING_CLASS_PATHS ./path/to/java/file.java`?